# Loading Image using Glide in Android

Tags: android, android-glide

I am trying to load an image from a URL into my imageview using glide but it is not working. I cannot download and display the image. I have added all the dependencies and permissions in my project but still it doesn't seem to work.Any idea whats going wrong? Here are all the files I have in my project.**The strange thing is I'm not getting any kind of error or exception in my logs**

```
////MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String imgUrl = "data:image/png;base64,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";

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    Glide.with(this)
            .load(imgUrl)
            .into(imageView);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.banty.gallaryapp.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.banty.gallaryapp">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

dependencies in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
// RecyclerView
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'

// volley
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

// Glide
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
}
```

Comment: is this the original image path

Comment: yes it is just a random image i picked from google

Comment: The code seems fine, have you tried other urls?

Comment: yes I have tried some other urls but they are all failing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of your image url, try with this (I removed the fist part, before the actual encode):

```
String imgBase64 = "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";

Glide.with(this)
        .load(Base64.decode(imgBase64, Base64.DEFAULT))
        .into(imageView);
```

Comment: I believe that approach will work, the image is encoded into a Base64 string, you need to convert it to a byte array then to a bitmap.

Comment: Thank you it worked, can you please explain what was the real issue and how you fixed it

Comment: You are welcome @Ezio I don't know if there is a way for loading directly a data-Uri. So, I would suggest to use that approach: converting your image into a byte array and then using the method `load(byte[] model)`.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Glide v4**:

```
String imgUrl = "data:image/png;base64,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";

Glide.with(this)
        .load(imgUrl)
        .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer [here](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/download-setup.html) and someone also post this following on stackoverflow. I tried several hour using above mentioned code but I got error. I can't explain but it's working for me

First step: post this into **build.gradle**

```
 implementation ("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0") {
    exclude group: "com.android.support"
}
// Glide v4 uses this new annotation processor -- see https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/generatedapi.html
annotationProcessor 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
implementation ("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0@aar") {
    transitive = true
}
```

Second step : create a empty public class and extends AppGlideMoudle and include

```
 import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule; 
 import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule;
 public class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {
 // empty class
 }
```

Last Step: add to MainActivity

```
 String urlimage= "url for the image";
        posterImageView = findViewById(R.id.imagePoster);
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(urlimage)
                .into(posterImageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

First add glide to build.`gradle(:app)`:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
```

Then, define your image in the `activity_main.xml`, like this:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
```

So, it's time for java part. `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppCompatImageView imageView;
    
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

imageView = findViewById(R.id.image);
Glide.with(this).load("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/computer-process-outline/64/start_new_beginning_go-512.png").
                placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background).error(R.drawable.broken_image).into(imageView);
    }
    }
```